# Formula Derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, education

What is the formula that can be derived using the values and formulas below to get the value of K43?

Here's what I have, so far, but no luck in getting the correct formula:

0 = 925191 - 119355 - (((39047 +y * (K3-J3))/((1+K5)^K1)) + ((38456+y*((L3-J3))/((1+K5)^L1)) + ((M32 + y * (M3 - J3)) / ((1 + K5)^M1)) + ((N32+y*(N3 - J3)) / ((1 + K5) ^ N1)) + ((O32+y*(O3-J3)) / ((1+ K5) ^ O1))) - (((((((39047 + (y * (K3 - J3))) + (K5 * 119355)) / ((119355 + ((39047(y * (K3 - J3))) + (K5 * 119355))* (1 - J24 ) + (K26*(K16*(1+K40)^K1))))) - K5) / (K5 - K37)) * (119355 + ((O32 + y * (O3 - J3)) + (K5 * J13)) * (1 - O24) + (O26* (K16 * ((1 + K40)) ^ 01)))))) / ((1 + K5) ^O1))

**VALUES FOR SOME VARIABLES:**

- J3 = 2015
- K3 = 2016
- J3 = 2015
- M3 = 2017
- N3 = 2018
- O3 = 2019
- K32 = 39047
- L32 = 38456
- M32 = 36685
- N32 = 32852
- 032 = 29019
- K5 = 0.09
- J13 = 119355
- K16 = 112
- K40 = 0.18
- K1 = 1
- L1 = 2
- M1 = 3
- N1 = 4
- O1 = 5
- P1 = 6
- J46 = 0
- J47 = 0
- J24 = 0.22
- K24 = 0.22
- L24 = 0.22
- M24 = 0.22
- O24 = 0.22
- P24 = 0.22
- J26 = 0
- K26 = 0
- L26 = 0
- M26 = 0
- N26 = 0
- O26 = 0
- P26 = 0
- K24 = 0.22
- K26 = 0
- P39 = 0.85
- O1 = 5
- K14 = 0
- K37 = 0.01
- K41 = 925191

**Equations:**

- K43 = ?
- K44 = K32+K43*(K3-J3)
- L44 = L32+K43*(L3-J3)
- M44 = M32+K43*(M3-J3)
- N44 = N32+K43*(N3-J3)
- O44 = O32+K43*(O3-J3)
- K45 = K5*K48
- L45 = K5*L48
- M45 = K5*M48
- N45 = K5*N48
- O45 = K5*O48
- K46 = K44 + K45
- L46 = L44 + L45
- M46 = M44 + M45
- N46 = N44 + N45
- O46 = O44 + O45
- K47 = K16*((1+K40)^K1)
- L47 = K16*((1+K40)^L1)
- M47 = K16*((1+K40)^M1)
- N47 = K16*((1+K40)^N1)
- O47 = K16*((1+K40)^O1)
- P47 = K16*((1+K40)^P1)
- K48 = J48+J46*(1-J24)+(J26*J47)
- L48 = K48+K46*(1-K24)+(K26*K47)
- M48 = L48+L46*(1-L24)+(L26*L47)
- N48 = M48+M46*(1-M24)+(M26*K47)
- O48 = N48+N46*(1-N24)+(N26*N47)
- P48 = O48+O46*(1-O24)+(O26*O47)
- K49 = K46/K48
- L49 = L46/L48
- M49 = M46/M48
- N49 = N46/N48
- O49 = O46/O48
- P50 = O49/P39
- K51 = K44/((1+K5)^(K1))
- L51 = L44/((1+K5)^(L1))
- M51 = M44/((1+K5)^(M1))
- N51 = N44/((1+K5)^(N1))
- O51 = O44/((1+K5)^(O1))
- P52 = K51 + L51 + M51 + N51+ O51
- P53 = (((P50-K5)/(K5-K37))*P48)/((1+K5)^O1)
- Q53 = K41-J13-P52-P53, WHERE Q53 IS ALWAYS 0

**Below are the equations with the given values:**

- K43 = ?
- K44 = 39047+K43*(2016-2015)
- L44 = 38456+K43*(2017-2015)
- M44 = 36685+K43*(2018-2015)
- N44 = 32852+K43*(2019-2015)
- O44 = 29019+K43*(2020-2015)
- K45 = 0.09*K48
- L45 = 0.09*L48
- M45 = 0.09*M48
- N45 = 0.09*N48
- O45 = 0.09*O48
- K46 = K44 + K45
- L46 = L44 + L45
- M46 = M44 + M45
- N46 = N44 + N45
- O46 = O44 + O45
- K47 = 112*((1+0.18)^1)
- L47 = 112*((1+0.18)^2)
- M47 = 112*((1+0.18)^3)
- N47 = 112*((1+0.18)^4)
- O47 = 112*((1+0.18)^5)
- P47 = 112*((1+0.18)^6)
- K48 = J48+0*(1-0.22)+(0*J47)
- L48 = K48+K46*(1-0.22)+(0*K47)
- M48 = L48+L46*(1-0.22)+(0*L47)
- N48 = M48+M46*(1-0.22)+(0*K47)
- O48 = N48+N46*(1-0.22)+(0*N47)
- P48 = O48+O46*(1-0.22)+(0*O47)
- K49 = K46/K48
- L49 = L46/L48
- M49 = M46/M48
- N49 = N46/N48
- O49 = O46/O48
- P50 = O49/0.85
- K51 = K44/((1+0.09)^(1))
- L51 = L44/((1+0.09)^(2))
- M51 = M44/((1+0.09)^(3))
- N51 = N44/((1+0.09)^(4))
- O51 = O44/((1+0.09)^(5))
- P52 = K51 + L51 + M51 + N51+ O51
- P53 = (((P50-0.09)/(0.09-0.01))*P48)/((1+0.09)^5)
- 0 = 925191-119355-P52-P53, WHERE Q53 IS ALWAYS 0

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @barakmanos I tried deriving a formula from the given equations: 0 = 925191 - 119355 - (((39047 +y * (K3-J3))/((1+K5)^K1)) + ((38456+y*((L3-J3))/((1+K5)^L1)) + ((M32 + y * (M3 - J3)) / ((1 + K5)^M1)) + ((N32+y*(N3 - J3)) / ((1 + K5) ^ N1)) + ((O32+y*(O3-J3)) / ((1+ K5) ^ O1))) - (((((((39047 + (y * (K3 - J3))) + (K5 * 119355)) / ((119355 + ((39047(y * (K3 - J3))) + (K5 * 119355))* (1 - J24 ) + (K26*(K16*(1+K40)^K1))))) - K5) / (K5 - K37)) * (119355 + ((O32 + y * (O3 - J3)) + (K5 * J13)) * (1 - O24) + (O26* (K16 * ((1 + K40)) ^ 01)))))) / ((1 + K5) ^O1)). Where y is K43

Comment: I doubt that anyone will ever bother to read all these tons of data, let alone provide an answer to your question. Please publish a summarized question containing the minimal amount of data required, explain exactly what problems you are facing trying to solve it on your own, and do it properly within the question (not as an **extremely unreadable** comment).

Comment: @barakmanos thank you for your suggestion, sir

Comment: There are more givens to be substituted than you have done so far. For instance, $P_{39}$ is known, but appears in the formula for $P_{50}$ in the section where givens were supposedly substituted into formulas.

Comment: @JustinBenfield thank you for the catch!

Comment: $K_{37}$ is known but not substituted for in the formula for $P_{53}$.

Comment: $J_{46}$ is known, but not substituted for in the formula for $K_{48}$. This gives that $K_{48}=J_{48}$.

Comment: @JustinBenfield done applying your comments.

Comment: Try simplifying each of the substituted equations as much as you can (work out arithmetic when possible (might want to not compute things like $(1.09)^6$ though because of lengthy decimal representation).

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thank you so much for your suggestions, sir! Really appreciate it!

Comment: This is the sort of problem for which computers were invented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer:

Working backwards from what we want to find $K_{43}$. We have equations containing it that also contain $Var_{44}$ Where $Var$ is each of $K,L,M,N,O$. Each $Var_{44}$ is related $Var_{45}$ and $Var_{46}$ by given equations, and each $Var_{45}$ is related to $Var_{48}$. Thus we can rewrite the $Var_{44}$ equations to contain $Var_{46}$ and $Var_{48}$. Now the $Var_{48}$'s are also related to each other sequentially in equations that also contain $Var_{46}$'s.

Edit:

After examining the variable relationships, I think you can find what you need by starting with the final equation,

$0=925191-119355-P_{52}-P_{53}$

Rearrange so that vars are on the left and perform indicated subtraction to obtain:

$P_{52}+P{53}=805836$

From here substitute formulas for both vars to obtain an expression involving the vars $Var_{51}$ from subbing $P_{52}$ and $P_{50}$ and $P_{48}$ from subbing for $P_{53}$.

Simplify as much as you can, then sub for the $Var_{51}$'s replacing them expressions in terms of w/ $Var_{44}$'s, and simplify. Then sub for the $Var_{44}$'s which are in terms of $K_{43}$. (We have taken care of everything that came from $P_{52}$ now. Now to handle the stuff from $P_{53}$).

Simplify as much as you can, then sub for $P_{50}$ and $P_{48}$ which replaces those vars with expressions involving $O_{49},O_{48},O_{46}$. $O_{49}$ can be re-expressed in terms of $O_{48}$ and $O_{46}$ (reducing vars by 1). $O_{46}$ can be expressed as in terms of $O_{45}$ and $O_{44}$. Express $O_{44}$ by using formula in terms of $K_{43}$. Express $O_{45}$ in terms of $O_{48}$.

Now we are ready to re-express $O_{48}$ in terms of $N_{46}$ and $N_{48}$. Once this is done we will repeat the pattern that happened one we had expressions for $O_{46}$ and $O_{48}$, but with $N$ instead of $O$. This obtains expressions in terms of $M_{46}$, and $M_{48}$.

This process is looped, each time moving 1-letter backwards in the alphabet until we are working on $K$'s, the process goes through, except that this time, we don't get $J_{46}$'s, but only $J_{48}$'s. Do you know the value of $J_{48}$? If not, then you can't isolate $K_{43}$ as desired, but if you *do*, then at the end of all of this, you can finally obtain $K_{43}$. Note that I *highly* recommend simplifying the equations after each substitution to reduce complexity and help avoid mistakes (try to minimize the number of times a var to be substituted appears before subbing for it).

Comment: Oh that's a great logic!